# How to deal with PeerConnection in Single Page App?

Tags: angularjs, html5-video, webrtc, html5-audio

I have a browser Single Page App that opens a PeerConnection to a video server and receives the media stream successfully. When the SPA leaves the page that is rendering the media, and then returns back to the render page, I do not want to have to re-establish the PeerConnection, but instead continue to render the media from the existing PeerConnection.

Question: what is the proper way to keep the PeerConnection rendering in the HTML5 video tag across different SPA pages?

I can see in the webrtc-internals page that the PeerConnection is not dropped after leaving the render page. But when I return back to the render page the video is black so the HTML5 video tag has obviously changed state.

Thanks,

-Andres

Comment: A peer connection very much stops when you leave a page. I suspect what you see in webrtc-internals is a snapshot for posthumous debugging. Some code might help clarify what you're asking.

Comment: It indeed appears that the PeerConnection is still very much alive. The server is still sending RTP/RTCP media and the browser is still receiving them and the webrtc-internals continues to to update its bitsReceivedPerSecond and bitsSentPerSecond graphs. The HTML5 video element goes to the Paused state when the page is changed. When I go back to the render page, the video element is grayed out and the controls do not visually operate, but I can click on them and indeed go back and forth between paused/play states but no video.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding what you mean with an "SPA page". Are you using some sort of framework?

Comment: By SPA page, I mean a different page in the application, but since it is an SPA app, its not a new browser page with a new URL but just a different "page" of the app.  I am using angular.js so every "page" of the app has its own angular scope and controller, but from the browser's point of view, there is only one URL-based page.